# Android Video Viewing Feature

Tags: android

Suppose a user is Watching a video and taps on the screen, then a bar comes in the bottom of the screen containing Play ,Pause etc....what do we call such kind of BAR..
If possible a sample code showing the Bar when user taps on the screen will be very usefull.Thank u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what do we call such kind of BAR

That is a `MediaController`.

> If possible a sample code showing the Bar when user taps on the screen will be very usefull

OK, [here you go](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video). The activity in question is rather simple:

```
package com.commonsware.android.video;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.io.File;

public class VideoDemo extends Activity {
    private VideoView video;
    private MediaController ctlr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                             "test.mp4");

        if (clip.exists()) {
            video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
            video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

            ctlr=new MediaController(this);
            ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
            video.setMediaController(ctlr);
            video.requestFocus();
            video.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u CommonsWare for your answer..But how can we create a customized bar for a media player without using media controller.

Comment: @user651377: Write a lot more code. See here for an example of that: https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry